# Watermarking Plugin Performance - Is FastScaling an Option?

Tags: imageresizer

I'm wanting to use ImageResizer to serve thumbnails that are scaled and watermarked on the fly on a high traffic website.

My testing has shown that the Watermarking plugin results in a significant decrease in throughput compared to just scaling them with FastScaling.

- Scaled: 150+ images per second
- Scaled & Watermarked: 35 images per second

I dug through the Watermark Plugin code and saw that it's using GDI+ for its image manipulations.  Is it possible to make it use the more performant FastScaling plugin instead?

Answer (score 0):

This is something we would like to improve. Currently, if either Watermarking (or the DRM red dot) are in use, performance reverts to GDI+ levels.

I would be happy to assist on a pull request for this, or discuss other options.

Comment: So I'd be interested in digging into this further.  I forked the code and spent some time digging through it earlier this week.  What's the best way to discuss options?